# Transform SQL Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a table that has the following format

```
RecordID FieldName FieldValue

1         Name      John
1         Age       30
2         Name      Alice
2         Age       40
```

We would like to present this as:

```
John   30
Alice  40
```

Anyone have a good solution for this?

Comment: Beware the inner platform effect: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
  TN.FieldValue AS ValueName
, TV.FieldValue AS ValueAge
FROM dbo.Table1 TN
INNER JOIN dbo.Table1 TV ON TN.RecordID = TV.RecordID
  AND TN.FieldName = 'Name'
  AND TV.FieldName = 'Age'
```

Answer (score 1):

Why didn't anybody use pivot?

```
declare @a TABLE(RecordId int, FieldName varchar(20), FieldValue varchar(20)) 

insert into @a select 1, 'Name', 'John' 
insert into @a select 1, 'Age', '30' 
insert into @a select 2, 'Name', 'Alice' 
insert into @a select 2, 'Age', '40' 

select *
from @a a pivot (max(FieldValue) for FieldName in (Name,Age)) p
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @a TABLE(RecordId int, FieldName varchar(20), FieldValue varchar(20))

insert into @a select 1, 'Name', 'John'
insert into @a select 1, 'Age', '30'
insert into @a select 2, 'Name', 'Alice'
insert into @a select 2, 'Age', '40'

select 
 records.RecordId 
 , name.fieldvalue [Name]
 , age.fieldvalue [Age]
from
 (select distinct recordid from @a) records
 inner join @a name on records.recordid = name.recordid and name.fieldname = 'Name'
 inner join @a age on records.recordid = age.recordid and age.fieldname = 'Age'
```

Answer (score 0):

This ain't pretty (but nor's the data), but this will work if your column names are known when you write the query:

```
SELECT 
RecordId, 
group_concat( if( FieldName = 'name', FieldValue, '' ) SEPARATOR '' ) AS person_name, 
group_concat( if( FieldName = 'age', FieldValue, '' ) SEPARATOR '' ) AS person_age
FROM test_table
GROUP BY RecordId
```

(works in MySQL 5.0)

You should also use CAST to get the fields to the correct type

If you don't know the fields, you'll need to (programatically) do a select distinct FieldName beforehand in order to build your query

I've a feeling the the Drupal Content Creation Kit (CCK) does something rather similar to this

Comment: There is no **group_concat** in SQL Server